# Why is x() == window if var x = [].reverse?

Tags: javascript

Something seemingly weird is going on in Google Chrome:

```
> var f = [].reverse;
undefined
> f() == window;
true
```

On Node.js, I get a different result:

```
> var f = [].reverse;
undefined
> f() == global;
TypeError: Array.prototype.reverse called on null or undefined
```

Why is this happening? Does it have to do with scoping?

Comment: @Robuust it is a function that reverses an array in-place. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[].reverse` is a function that operates on `this`.

For instance, when called as `[1,2].reverse()`, `this` is that `[1,2]` array, and it returns `[2,1]`.

However, if you just call `f()`, then you are calling the function with no context. In a browser, that means the default context of `window` is passed (unless you're in Strict Mode), and on the server you get an error basically telling you that `this` is undefined.

Try `f.call([1,2])`

Comment: Do you have a reference for how node.js handles the default `this`?

Answer (score 2):

The function [`Array.prototype.reverse`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.8) returns `this`. When you call it as `f()`, it loses the `this` information it would have in a call like `[].reverse()`. Outside of strict mode, the default `this` is `window`, so that's what gets returned.

Comment: Does Node.js evaluate everything in strict mode by default, or does it merely exhibit different behaviour w.r.t. the global object?

Comment: @rightfold: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about node.js to answer that.